# Stored Procedure returns different result than Query

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mariadb

I am trying to use a Mysql(MariDB) Stored-Procedure of a simple query with one parameter. However, the results of the invoked Procedure differs from the initial query, and I don't understand why.

Here is My initial Query:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT * FROM ob1.eco_serie WHERE TS_ID = 3;
+-----+-------+---------------------+---------------------+------+
| id  | TS_ID | Date_period         | Date_publi          | Val  |
+-----+-------+---------------------+---------------------+------+
|   4 |     3 | 1996-10-31 00:00:00 | 1996-11-01 00:00:00 | 50.5 |
|   5 |     3 | 1996-11-30 00:00:00 | 1996-12-02 00:00:00 |   53 |
|   6 |     3 | 1996-12-31 00:00:00 | 1997-01-02 00:00:00 | 55.2 |
 ...       ...  ...........           .............         ...
```

Then I make a Stored-Procedure of this Query:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> CREATE PROCEDURE ob1.GET_eco_serie (IN par_serie_ID INT)
    -> BEGIN
    -> SELECT * FROM ob1.eco_serie WHERE TS_ID = par_serie_ID;
    -> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)
```

But, when I call this Procedure with the same parameters as before, I get an empty result:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> CALL ob1.GET_eco_serie(@3);
Empty set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Any idea what is going on here? Thanks.

Comment: Have you declared variable @3?

Comment: I don't get what you mean by that, so probably not. Could you explain?

Comment: It is impossible, unless you dont have a value to your SP Parameter.

Comment: No need to use @ in front of the number 3.

Comment: Thank you Shadow. That works like a charm with your Answer.

Comment: 2 ways to pass parameter to stored procedure 1) as is eg 3 if passing an integer 2) by using a set statement prior to the call eg set @3 = 3 and then using the variable in the call eg call sp(@3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call a procedure like this:

```
CALL ob1.GET_eco_serie(3);
```

Just remove @ sign